# How to take multiple input in multiple line in python

Tags: python, input, data-structures

I have to take multiple input in multiple lines

for example

```
n=int(input())
```

I have to take n input in n line and each line take multiple input

```
if n=5
then I have to take 5 input in 5  line
a=[1,2,3]
b=[1,2,3]
c=[1,2,3]
d=[1,2,3]
e=[1,2,3]
```

like this is just an example.

Comment: use a for loop and then you can split the multiple input based on delimiter

Comment: I don't think this clearly describes the expected inputs and outputs of this program. If `n` is `5` why do each of your variables have 3 elements? Where do those values come from? What exactly does a user type in order to get that particular output? If you could clarify your expected inputs and outputs or other rules for the program, folks will be able to help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be what you need...

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    exec(input())
print(a, b, c, d, e)
```